# how to subclass properties in superclass by using inheritance?

Tags: oop

i want to ask a question about inheritance. we say that in inheritance there is a subclass and a superclass. subclass get all the properties of superclass. but my question is how a superclass get the properties of a subclass. 
Like if we have two classes class A and class B. class B is derived from class A . so class B have all the properties of class A but if we want to access any property of class B by using class A how can we do this???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**but my question is how a superclass get the properties of a subclass.**

In java: 
Inheritance does not work in the opposite direction, child just inherit the properties of the parent not in the opposite direction.

Comment: this question is asked by one of the interviewer in the interview so i get confused i also think that inheritance did not work in opposite way but i am not sure about it

Comment: yes, that can not be done in java, just you can retrieve or have access to the parent properties from the child class not in the opposite direction , I suppose this behavior are in other language.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the properties of a subclass from the superclass. if A is the subclass of B then A has all functionality that B has that have not been overridden. B only has the functionality of B and all of the parent classes of B.